# Different width for select and option tag Dropdown

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu which has different width for select and option tags :-

```
#select{
width:150px;
>option{
width:210px;
}
}
```

this code is working fine in all other browsers except for IE7 & IE8 . In these browsers, option tags are also using width as 150px. How to fix this ?? please help....

Comment: can you give us the html code of your dropdown? or if possible a jsfiddle?

Comment: That’s not really valid CSS code that you supplied here. Anyway, if you don’t want to go with a JS approach as in Kees’ answer, I would probably just make the select element 210px wide anyways for older IE … shitty browser, therefor less (accurate) design/layout … who cares.

Comment: Did you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

An example I found uses just css and a bit javascript to change the width onclick.

```
<style>
.ctrDropDown{
    width:145px;
    font-size:11px;
}
.ctrDropDownClick{
    font-size:11px;

    width:300px;

}
.plainDropDown{
    width:145px;
    font-size:11px;
}
</style>
<div style="padding:4px;width:175px;height:75px;border:thin solid black;overflow:hidden;">
I am the problem select list:<br><br>
<select name="someDropDown" id="someDropDown" class="plainDropDown">
    <option value="">This is option 1.</option>
    <option value="">This is the second option, a bit longer.</option>
    <option value="">Drink to me only with thine eyes, and I will pledge with mine...</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<hr width="150px;" align="left">
<br>
<div style="padding:4px;width:175px;height:75px;border:thin solid black;overflow:hidden;">
I am the better select list:<br><br>
<select name="someDropDown" id="someDropDown" class="ctrDropDown" onBlur="this.className='ctrDropDown';" onMouseDown="this.className='ctrDropDownClick';" onChange="this.className='ctrDropDown';">
    <option value="">This is option 1.</option>
    <option value="">This is the second option, a bit longer.</option>
    <option value="">Drink to me only with thine eyes, and I will pledge with mine...</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm)

Also a JSFIDDLE: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TccY7/1/)

Hope it helps!